# Help with disk partitions - cannot add adjacent free space to my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, disk-management

I know there are many questions about this topic, but I could not find an answer to my particular case.
I have a dual-boot configuration on my 500 GB single hard drive, and I needed to add some space to my Ubuntu.

I have freed 7292 MB of space inside Windows in order to fix that, but now I am in the condition of being unable to add that space to Ubuntu (40 GiB partition), even if the free space appears to be adjacent to my root partition.

Here's a screenshot of my hard disk situation:

[image]

How do I add the free space to my Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, are you booted into your Ubuntu system? If so, you can't make any edits to its partition. Reboot into a live system.

In your live system, after you've set the unallocated space, right click on the Ubuntu ext4 partition and click "Resize/Move." You should be able to move the partition to the start of the unallocated space and increase its size.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes, I am currently inside Ubuntu. In order to boot into a live system, do I have to have something like an .iso of an Ubuntu image, for instance? Or can I do it in the bios?

Comment: Yes, you need a piece of bootable media (for example, a USB stick) with the live ubuntu image flashed onto it. Take a look at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started

Comment: Sorry, one more question - Will this process delete my files or will it just let me add those 7 GB without any issue?

Comment: Since there's nothing on the 7 GB, you won't lose anything. However, resizing and moving partitions is somewhat risky, and I would recommend backing up the data on the partition you're moving and resizing (ubuntu partition)

Comment: Well, I actually meant files inside my root partition (ubuntu partition), but I think your answer still solves my doubt. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Be careful with resize though if you have no backup on your ubuntu partition since its slightly risky